# JanusGraph 0.2.0 unable to access ConfiguredGraphFactory from Gremlin console

Tags: janusgraph

I have started `gremlin-server` using the `gremlin-server-configuration.yaml` config file. `gremlin-server` started without any issue, but when I tried to access `ConfiguredGraphFactory` from the Gremlin console, I got the following exception:

> org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.utils.ConfigurationManagementGraphNotEnabledException

Not sure whether of whether I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your gremlin-server yaml have the property mentioned in 8.7 of this document : 
 http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/configuredgraphfactory.html#configuring-JanusGraph-server-for-configuredgraphfactory?

Is the database in the configuration file accessible?

Comment: I am using the gremlin-server-configuration.yaml file to start the gremlin-server and it refer the file janusgraph-cassandra-configurationgraph.properties for the storage.backend related details. I have compared it with the document, it looks similar. I am using Cassandra backend with thrift enabled.

Comment: For some weird reason, its working now. Thanks for taking time and answering the question.

Comment: No problem! :-)